# Laravel 5: Lazy Eager Loading without repeating queries

Tags: php, laravel, orm, laravel-5, eloquent

In my project I'm writing a method on one of my models that uses one of it's relationships and a sub-relationship so I am having to use lazy eager loading:

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        // Lazy eager load relationship and subrelationship
        $this->load('relationship', 'relationship.subrelationship');

        $relatedItems = $this->relationship;
        foreach ($relatedItems as $relatedItem) {
            $subrelatedItems = $relatedItem->subrelationship;
            foreach ($subrelatedItems as $subrelatedItem) {
                // Do something...
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The `Model::load()` method in Laravel can be used to re-load a relationship and does a new database query every time. Therefore, each time I call my method `MyModel::doSomething()`, (Or call another method that uses similar relationships) another database query is executed.

I know that in Laravel you can call a relationship a number of times like this:

```
$relatedItems = $model->relationship;
$relatedItems = $model->relationship;
$relatedItems = $model->relationship;
$relatedItems = $model->relationship;
```

..and it doesn't repeat the query since it has already loaded the relationship.

I was wondering if it was possible to avoid querying the database every time I want to use my relationship inside the model? I had the idea that I could use `$this->getRelations()` to work out which relationships had been loaded and then just skip them if they already had:

```
$toLoad = ['relationship', 'relationship.subrelationship'];
$relations = $this->getRelations();
foreach ($toLoad as $relationship) {
    if (array_key_exists($relationship, $relations)) {
        unset($toLoad[$relationship]);
    }
}

if (count($toLoad) > 0) {
    $this->load($toLoad);
}
```

That works to an extent, it's able to skip loading `relationship` each time, but `relationship.subrelationship` isn't actually stored in the array returned by `$this->getRelations()`. I would imagine it is stored in the sub-model(s) as `subrelationship`.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is, that you're creating the function in the Model file. And that kind of limits you and you have to load the relationship every time.

What I would do is create a function which takes the model objects you want to doSomething with as arguments. Let me clarify:

**Define a function**

Now if you're following a design pattern you probably have a place to put the function in. Otherwise put it where you'd normally put it.

```
public function doSomething($myModels)
{
    $relatedItems = $myModels->relationship;
    foreach ($relatedItems as $relatedItem) {
        $subrelatedItems = $relatedItem->subrelationship;
        foreach ($subrelatedItems as $subrelatedItem) {
            // Do something...
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Now when calling the function, pass the models with the relationship.

For example

```
$myModels = MyModel::where('created_at', <, Carbon::now())->with('relationship')->get();
doSomething($myModels)
```

If you need to load several or deeper relationships you can do

```
...->with('relationship.subrelationship', 'secondrelationship')->get()
```

The code isn't tested but I think you get the point. Look into [with()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I understand what you're saying. In my case, I think that the method is suitable for the model. Given a user object (By `Auth::user()` I'm trying to find out something about that user) so using `with` is quite difficult since the model is already loaded. I'm trying to achieve something similar to what `with` does in that I want to load my relationships and then just use them normally without running into the n+1 problem. Really appreciate your answer though - thanks!

Comment: How are you retrieving the model? Before calling `->get()` or `->first()`  you can call `->with()` and it's also loaded.

Comment: I was retrieving the model using `Auth::user()` and then I was calling the relationships like `$this->relationship` i.e. the magic method. I have tried `$this->relationship()->with('subrelationship')->get()` but that still means repeated queries since doing that doesn't store the relationship in the `relations` property. I have just figured a way around this problem though, if you bear with me a moment while I post an answer. Thanks a lot for your suggestions though.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to work out a way around this problem. Originally I had something like this:

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    public function relationship()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Related');
    }
}

class Related extends Model
{
    public function subrelated()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Subrelated');
    }
}

class Subrelated extends Model
{

}
```

After a lot of digging round in the Laravel source, I have found that when you call a relationship like it's a property using a magic method (namely `__get()`), Laravel stores it in the models `$relations` property for use later. With that in mind I added another method to `MyModel` like this:

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    public function relationship()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Related');
    }

    public function relationshipWithSubrelated()
    {
        return $this->relationship()->with('subrelated');
    }
}
```

Now I can call the relationship like the following as many times as I need to and it always gives me the same results:

```
$myModel = MyModel::find(1);
$myModel->relationshipWithSubrelated;
```

Wish I thought of it before I spent hours trying to work around!